# Android devices don't show up in "adb devices" until logged into Ubuntu GUI session

Tags: android, ubuntu, adb, gnome

We have thousands of devices that we test on hundreds of Ubuntu hosts and one of the big problems we're running into is that unless you log into the host via the GUI, some of the devices don't show up.  I was speaking with a coworker and he was saying this was due to the device being unable to mount until an active GNOME session was started, but he didn't know how to fix it - does anyone know a way around this?  This is a huge problem for us because if we need to reboot a host (or many hosts), we need to remote into each one, log in, and then the devices show up - logging in via Putty doesn't have any effect - it's only if you log into the GUI that the devices show up.

Our systems are running Ubuntu 16.04.

```
sudo adb kill-server
sudo adb devices
```

Has been tried, and does not help.

Thanks!

Comment: *We have thousands of devices that we test on hundreds of Ubuntu hosts* - do you mind sharing the name of your organization? Just making sure I am not employed by the same company.

Answer (score 1):

### Create this file as root if it's not created already:

`touch /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules`

### Use this format to add each vendor id from your devices to the file:

> SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="12d1", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"

In this example, the vendor ID is for my HUAWEI device. The MODE assignment specifies read/write permissions so when you have created/updated the file, execute.

### Make the file executable:

`chmod +x /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules`

### Now try restart adb again.

`adb kill-server; adb start-server; adb devices -l`

If you do not know your vendor ID i have created a list for the most known brands for you, otherwise the vendor ID can be found by lsusb command if you got this package installed, the bolded text is your Vendor ID if the phone is listed.

### List devices Vendor ID via lsusb:

`lsusb`

> Bus 002 Device 019: ID **12d1** :107e Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd.

### List Vendor ID's for different phone models via curl:

`curl -L https://nr1.nu/xm89`

> SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0502", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev" #Acer
>   SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0b05", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev" #ASUS

---

I assume you know that the phone is connected properly already but if you are not sure about this type dmesg -w followed by connecting the device to your pc again, you should see a message that a new device has been found if everything is okey.

Comment: We've got the rules file above in place and it still doesn't work.  That being said, my coworker said something about removing the 69-libmtpa rules file and that will stop the devices from trying to mount themselves as MTP devices, but I haven't tried that yet.  I'll give it a shot and check back in if that fixes the issue...

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
adb kill-server
adb devices
```

adb server will be restarted hence there is a change to detect the connected devices